# Modify bash arguments and pass to java program

Tags: java, bash, shell, unix

Is it possible to modify the arguments passed to a bash program ? and then pass them to a Java program ?

I know we can access all the arguments passed to a bash program by `"$@"` and I can pass them to Java program like `java com.myserver.Program "$@"`. But is it possible to modify value of certain arguments inside `"$@"` and then call the above java program with `"$@"` ?

I also know you can use `"$@[1]"` to access the value of arguments but how can we iterate over them and change the value at the proper position ? 
I also know this :

```
for arg
do
....
done
```

But inside the do loop how can the value of argument be modified and then java program be called ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate through every item in the positional parameters, then add them to another array, modifying it if needed while you do.

```
ARGS=()
for A in "$@"; do
    # Modify A then add it to args. 
    # A=${A//something/something} ## Just an example.
    ARGS+=("$A")
done

# Then call java:

java com.myserver.Program "${ARGS[@]}"
```

And since you're processing positional parameters, it would be simpler to use this form of `for`:

```
for A; do
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3156914/1291961. But how can I pass that as argument to Java class?

Comment: @WarriorPrince On my example it's `java com.myserver.Program "${ARGS[@]}"`.

Comment: Yes Just saw the edit. Awesome it worked. Thank you very much for detailed explanation.